# using crumbs mixture multiple times [is it safe?]

Tags: breadcrumbs, salmonella

I made a crumbs mixture for chicken breast strips. I coated them in beaten eggs, then coated them in crumbs mixture and fried. I have leftovers and I would like to just put this into a bag to use later time.

My mother said not to do it because there was egg in it, and it can contain salmonella or something - but my thinking is: I'm gonna fry it anyway so salmonella will get killed by heat. But I don't know.

Is it OK to use crumbs mixture after I mixed it with chicken coated with eggs? I'm talking using it like week later, not the next day.

Answer (score 3):

In my mind, salmonella is not the issue here. I would be generally worried about *who knows what* growing in the crumb-and-egg mixture over the course of a week.

Whole eggs, uncooked and in the shell, take a surprisingly long time to expire (even longer if you have farm eggs that haven't had the [cuticle](http://imaginationstationtoledo.org/content/2011/04/the-anatomy-of-a-chicken-egg/) washed off). But once you crack them open and mix them with other ingredients, you drastically increase their capacity to serve as a growth medium for microorganisms.

My advice to you is **do not reuse such a mixture after the cooking session during which it was prepared.** Is it going to hurt you to put it in the fridge overnight, and then use it to make some cutlets for breakfast the next day? I doubt it. But we're not talking about caviar and saffron here; bread crumbs are cheap, and a little egg and seasoning is easy to throw together next time you need it.

If you're concerned about convenience, season the bread crumbs and put them in a resealable bag. Store this bag in a cool place and take just as much of the bread crumb mixture as needed each time you want to make a breading. Use a new egg each time and throw away the excess.